# Jackson: Register fallback deserializer for unknown properties

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Is there a way in `Jackson` to register a custom deserializer (using annotations or another way) for unknown properties? Something like a fallback deserializer, called instead of throwing `UnrecognizedPropertyException`.

NOTE: I do not want to ignore unknown properties, I want to collect them.

Comment: Did you tried `ExceptionMapper`?

Comment: No, I did not try `ExceptionMapper` yet.

Comment: @Andremoniy: Do you mean `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper`? I do not see how it fit here, 
I would like to catch an event when unknown property occurs, process the property and let `ObjectMapper` continue desrialization on the the rest of the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `@JsonAnySetter` annotation might help.
See how-to guide here 
http://vincentdevillers.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/how-to-map-unknown-json-properties-with.html

Comment: `Map<String, Object> other = new HashMap<String, Object>();` even handles nested objects. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can also answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064951/jackson-handling-of-remaining-fields